# How to get the visible monitor width in MFC?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors. If all monitors are on, I could use the following to get the visible width:

```
::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
```

However, if I unplugged the second monitor and call this function again, I still get the width of both monitors (not the only visible one). Any suggestion on what I can do?

Comment: "if I unplugged the second monitor" - does Windows still think the second monitor is attached, i.e. can you move your mouse into it even when it's off? If so I doubt you're going to be able to detect this.

Comment: Obviously Windows still thinks that monitor is part of the virtual screen. This is a problem that needs to be addressed in your "Display"  control panel, not through code. There's nothing wrong with `SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Try `SM_CXSCREEN` or `SM_CXFULLSCREEN`.
2. Try [GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with HORZSIZE
3. Try [GetMonitorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).